# Currency mask with jQuery

Tags: jquery, currency, input-mask

I'm using the jQuery calculation and have just about everything working properly, but I need the total to display as 99.90, not 99.9 (for example).

So `.toFixed()` isn't working for some reason when it should be! I can't find a mask that would work with this problem. Anyone have any other ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of this line:

```
$(".sumit").sum("keyup", "#totalSum");
```

Use:

```
$('.sumit').keyup(function(){
  var totalsum = $('.sumit').sum();
  $('#totalSum').val(Number(totalsum).toFixed(2));
});
```

Hope that helps

Comment: Tried it. Still getting the same result. I'm wondering if the calculation has an overwrite within it?

Comment: The calculation is done before formatting the number so it shouldn't be that. Still staring at the code and scratching my head ;)

Comment: Aha, I think the variable totalsum is a string not a number, so .toFixed doesn't exist. Updating original answer with new code

Comment: Perfect! Was right over my head! Input values are strings, you have to convert to a number. Thanks Al!

Answer (score 3):

You can use toFixed

```
var num = 99.9;
num.toFixed(2);
```